# Return the Nth oldest child from a prolog query

Tags: prolog

```
child(john, mary).
child(john, martinez).
child(john, maggie).

age(mary, 11).
age(martinez, 12).
age(maggie, 13).
```

What I would like to do is define a query that returns the Nth oldest child of a person, in this case John. E.G. 1st oldest, would be Maggie. 2nd oldest would be Martinez, and 3rd oldest would be Mary.

I'm new to prolog, and the tutorials provided on the website are written in some archaic flash-script that has long since been dead and unsupported so I'm kind of in the dark here. Thank you in advance for helping with this.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to collect all children in a list and then sort them. Look at _findall_  predicate.

Comment: `tutorials provided on the website` Which website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make a `QUERY` that get's all children of the `PERSON0` .
2. form the result so that `AGE` comes first in the term .
3. use `setof` for the query so that the results are sorted by `AGE` youngest to oldest .
4. reverse the youngest to oldest list to get an oldest to youngest list .
5. obtain the `NTH` element from the list of oldest to youngest .

```
nth__oldest__child(NTH0,PERSON0,NTH_CHILD,NTH_AGE)
:-
QUERY=(child(PERSON0,CHILD) , age(CHILD,AGE)) ,
FORM=(age___child(AGE,CHILD)) ,
prolog:setof(FORM,QUERY,YOUNGEST_TO_OLDESTs) ,
lists:reverse(YOUNGEST_TO_OLDESTs,OLDEST_TO_YOUNGESTs) ,
lists:nth1(NTH0,OLDEST_TO_YOUNGESTs,age___child(NTH_AGE,NTH_CHILD))
.

/*
?- nth__oldest__child(1,john,CHILD,AGE) .
CHILD = maggie,
AGE = 13.

?- nth__oldest__child(2,john,CHILD,AGE).
CHILD = martinez,
AGE = 12.

?- nth__oldest__child(3,john,CHILD,AGE).
CHILD = mary,
AGE = 11.

?- nth__oldest__child(4,john,CHILD,AGE).
false.

?-
*/
```

Answer (score 3):

Compare the children's ages. P is unified with <, > or =

```
ch_compare(P, C1, C2) :- age(C1, A1), age(C2, A2), compare(P, A2, A1).
```

Collect all children, sort them and then pick the nth oldest.

```
nth_child_of(N, Parent, Child) :-
  findall(C, child(Parent, C), Children),
  predsort(ch_compare, Children, Sorted), 
  nth1(N, Sorted, Child).
```

I suggest you read up on the predicates `findall/3`, `predsort/3`.

EDIT: If you want the list of children ordered by age then you have

```
ch_compare(P, C1, C2) :- age(C1, A1), age(C2, A2), compare(P, A2, A1).
children(Parent, Children) :-
  findall(C, child(Parent, C), Unsorted),
  predsort(ch_compare, Unsorted, Children).
```

Comment: This is more than I could have hoped for, thank you.

Comment: @RozarNatrim : accept an answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: It's not quite resolving as I think you expect.

nth_child_of(Parent) :-
    findall(C, is_child_of(C, Parent), Children).

also does not resolve the way I expect (note that I swapped, C and parent). Which is the way that I described it. 

Not sure why a list is not returned.

Comment: Can you show me your final code? I could not make sense of your changes. Why is your `nth_child_of` a unary predicate?

Comment: @RozarNatrim You want the list of a persons children, sorted in descending order of age?